# Laravel model save() method not returning correct ID?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have the following simple code which iterates over some data, creates a `Bedroom`, and then attaches `Beds` to each `Bedroom`.

```php
foreach ($data as $room) {
    $r = new Bedroom();
    $r->name = $room['name'];
    $r->save();
    foreach ($room['beds'] as $bed) {
        $b = new Bed();
        $b->name = $bed['name'];
        $b->bedroom_id = $r->id;  // (A)
        $b->save();  // (B)
    }
}
```

I am getting a foreign key constraint error at (B) because the room id at (A) does not exist. This doesn't seem possible to me unless there is some delay going on after the `$r->save()`, or the `$r->id` is inconsistent with the database. This appears to be fixed by replacing (B) with `$r->beds()->save($b);`. Why?

Comment: Are you using 'id' as the primary key?

Comment: Yes, with auto increments

Comment: From this code snippet I cant see why one would work and not the other, as both would require an id to update.  The fix you have put is because Laravel would then use the eloquent relationship to populate the bedroom_id field, but I cant see how $r would not have an id if saved.  you could try dd($r) to see if its getting an id on save.

Comment: One more possibility would be, bedroom_id doesn't exist in table, so then you get a constraint violation, because foreign key is not nullable

Comment: The OP has said the error is "because the room id at (A) does not exist.".  So it wont be bedroom_id if that is the case.

Comment: Try to dump the saved object  with `dd($r)` after creating, you should see what properties are available